# Image rendering in MAUI project

Tags: c#, image, rendering, maui

Is there any technique to render the images more clearly in `MAUI`, like `RenderOption` in `WPF`.

My image must be like this:

[image]

and it is rendered like this:

[image]

**Edit:** This project will run only on Windows Desktop and MacCatalyst. This behavior is happening on Windows device.
The OS is Windows 11 x64

Image xaml:

```cs
<Border
    Grid.Row="1"
    Margin="3"
    HeightRequest="140"
    StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 1,1,1,1"
    WidthRequest="140">
    <Border.Stroke>Black</Border.Stroke>
    <Border.StrokeThickness>0.3</Border.StrokeThickness>
    <Image
        Margin="1"
        Aspect="AspectFill"
        Background="{StaticResource Gray100}"
        HeightRequest="130"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        Source="{Binding MyImage}"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        WidthRequest="130" />
</Border>
```

In action:

[image: InAction]

Comment: Without more information, it is unknown why you are getting this result. First, make sure you view on an actual device, not emulator. (Or take screenshot inside an emulator, and make sure the screenshot has same pixel count as a device that you care about.) Second, what are the pixel dimensions of your source image? And how many device pixels are in the region that is displaying the second image? Third, show the xaml of the image element that is showing that image. [Please answer these questions by editing your question; if you respond via comments, it will be harder to read.]

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve , based on your comment I've edited my question. I must say that I've posted this as an issue to GitHub MAUI's project.

Answer (score 1):

As a summary, I will post an answer so that it will help others who have similar problems. Thanks for your support and feedback @ValiMatie.

The posted issue is here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10916 .

And it has been moved to Backlog milestone. This means that it is not going to be worked on for the coming release.